# "Too many values to unpack" in numpy histogram2d

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, histogram2d

I am using numpy histogram2d to compute the values for the visual representation of a 2d histogram of two variables:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(Z[:,0], Z[:,1], bins=100)
```

where Z is a numpy matrix

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/.../pca_analysis.py", line 141, in <module>
   H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(Z[:,0], Z[:,1], bins=100)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 615, in histogram2d
   hist, edges = histogramdd([x,y], bins, range, normed, weights)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 281, in histogramdd
   N, D = sample.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I cannot really understand why I am getting this error. I have tried using the histogram2d function with random values and it is working properly. I have also tried to transform both Z[:,0] and Z[:,1] in numpy arrays and simple lists, but I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: Z is a matrix, make it an array

Comment: @seberg, I have already tried by doing np.array(Z[...]), but I get the same error

Comment: have you? `np.asarray(Z)[:,0]`...

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. I was doing it in the wrong way

Comment: @seberg please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @seberg notes in the comments, `Z` is a matrix, so it must be cast as an array before slicing.

```py
np.asarray(Z)[:,0]
```

The reason this is necessary is because the `np.matrix` maintains its two-dimensionality even after slicing, so that the column of matrix has shape `(N,1)`, not `(N,)` as the histogram functions expect.

The reason it doesn't work to cast to an array *after* slicing is that the shape is unchanged by casting; the behavior of slicing is what is different.

In case that doesn't make sense, here's an illustration:

```py
In [4]: a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [6]: m = np.matrix(a)

In [7]: m
Out[7]: 
matrix([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])

In [8]: m[:,0]
Out[8]: 
matrix([[0],
        [3],
        [6]])

In [9]: a[:,0]
Out[9]: array([0, 3, 6])

In [10]: m[:,0].shape
Out[10]: (3, 1)

In [11]: a[:,0].shape
Out[11]: (3,)
```

If you cast after slicing, the shape is still 2d:

```py
In [12]: np.array(m[:,0])
Out[12]: 
array([[0],
       [3],
       [6]])

In [13]: np.array(m[:,0]).shape
Out[13]: (3, 1)
```